# PostgreSQL - Extremely slow COUNT / GROUP_BY query

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this which stores file operation logs on a computer:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_logs_file_ops(
log_id bigserial primary key,
username VARCHAR(255),
computer VARCHAR(255),
activity VARCHAR(255),
is_directory bool,
event_type VARCHAR(255),
src text,
dst text,
event_time timestamp(6));
```

And I run the following query on it to retrieve the names of the files that are the top 10 most used:

```
SELECT src, COUNT(src)
        FROM tbl_logs_file_ops
        GROUP BY src
        ORDER BY COUNT(src) DESC
        NULLS LAST
        LIMIT 10
```

The table has ~3 million rows and it currently takes about 40 seconds to finish this query. But I need it to be much faster on a much larger dataset.

I've learned about indexing and added the following index to the table:

```
CREATE INDEX top_file_desc_index ON tbl_logs_file_ops (src DESC NULLS LAST);
```

But that has not improved the query speed any bit. What am I missing? How can I improve the speed of such queries?

Output of explain(analyze, verbose, buffers):

```
    "QUERY PLAN"
"Limit  (cost=10000876798.05..10000876798.08 rows=10 width=139) (actual time=125352.270..125352.274 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Output: src, (count(src))"
"  Buffers: shared hit=2974 read=79483 dirtied=597, temp read=156882 written=157095"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=10000876798.05..10000877028.85 rows=92318 width=139) (actual time=125097.633..125097.635 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Output: src, (count(src))"
"        Sort Key: (count(tbl_logs_file_ops.src)) DESC NULLS LAST"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=2974 read=79483 dirtied=597, temp read=156882 written=157095"
"        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=10000851212.26..10000874803.09 rows=92318 width=139) (actual time=113240.333..124896.852 rows=903094 loops=1)"
"              Output: src, count(src)"
"              Group Key: tbl_logs_file_ops.src"
"              Buffers: shared hit=2974 read=79483 dirtied=597, temp read=156882 written=157095"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=10000851212.26..10000858768.14 rows=3022354 width=131) (actual time=113240.278..124149.192 rows=3018673 loops=1)"
"                    Output: src"
"                    Sort Key: tbl_logs_file_ops.src"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 422672kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2974 read=79483 dirtied=597, temp read=156882 written=157095"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.tbl_logs_file_ops  (cost=10000000000.00..10000112680.54 rows=3022354 width=131) (actual time=0.024..795.934 rows=3018673 loops=1)"
"                          Output: src"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=2974 read=79483 dirtied=597"
"Planning Time: 0.209 ms"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 8"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 2.582 ms, Inlining 14.640 ms, Optimization 169.266 ms, Emission 70.453 ms, Total 256.941 ms"
"Execution Time: 125436.075 ms"
```

work_mem is 4MB. Below is the output of explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) after setting the work_mem to 2GB:

```
 "QUERY PLAN"
"Limit  (cost=10000465717.01..10000465717.03 rows=10 width=141) (actual time=114351.538..114351.547 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Output: src, (count(src))"
"  Buffers: shared hit=5143 read=77806"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=10000465717.01..10000465964.26 rows=98901 width=141) (actual time=114133.937..114133.944 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Output: src, (count(src))"
"        Sort Key: (count(tbl_logs_file_ops.src)) DESC NULLS LAST"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=5143 read=77806"
"        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=10000439841.77..10000463579.79 rows=98901 width=141) (actual time=112704.879..113965.053 rows=911901 loops=1)"
"              Output: src, count(src)"
"              Group Key: tbl_logs_file_ops.src"
"              Buffers: shared hit=5143 read=77806"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=10000439841.77..10000447424.77 rows=3033202 width=133) (actual time=112704.830..113141.553 rows=3036619 loops=1)"
"                    Output: src"
"                    Sort Key: tbl_logs_file_ops.src"
"                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 746279kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=5143 read=77806"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.tbl_logs_file_ops  (cost=10000000000.00..10000113281.02 rows=3033202 width=133) (actual time=0.029..948.635 rows=3036619 loops=1)"
"                          Output: src"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=5143 read=77806"
"Planning Time: 0.223 ms"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 8"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 3.429 ms, Inlining 16.132 ms, Optimization 147.881 ms, Emission 53.287 ms, Total 220.729 ms"
"Execution Time: 114371.484 ms"
```

Comment: try this: 1. vacuum the whole database. 2. change your order with 'order by 2 desc limit 10' you have null las ti the index

Comment: @MitkoKeckaroski: changing the order by will not make any difference

Comment: Could you share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) ? And what the setting for work_mem ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens added the info you've requested

Comment: It's sorting on disk because the database is not allowed to use more then 4MB of memory. No idea how much RAM you have, but work_mem should be imho at least 1GB.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I've tried 1GB and 2GB with no improvement at all. I also observe that it does a sequential scan despite the fact that I disabled the option.

Comment: This is your problem:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 422672kB. And that happens because you don't give the database enough RAM. Change the setting, use explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)  again and see the differences. With enough RAM, the database won't sort on disk.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Added output of explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) after setting the memory to 2GB. I can see that it's sorting on memory now but it's still very slow. It's not using the index and does a sequential scan.

Comment: How did you disable the sequential read? And how sure are about the status for this setting? SHOW enable_seqscan; But the database should already prefer an index scan when that makes sense, but that depends on your data and your configuration

Comment: @FrankHeikens I noticed that I had dropped the index so that was the reason... Thank you for your help. Now I'm facing a different issue though. The same query executes fast on pgadmin4 but it's still very slow when it's executed through an API call

Comment: Are you on the same database server?

Comment: @FrankHeikens not on the same server but on the same local network

Comment: When that's a different database server/cluster, the configuration might be different, the data might be different and the index could be missing as well.